# Laravel 7.0 streaming HLS videos has CORS issues

Tags: laravel, cors, http-live-streaming, laravel-7

I am implementing HLS video streaming in Laravel 7.0 and Nuxt JS. CORS is enable don Laravel and videos are transcoded to `.m3u8` format and saved in a public disk. But when I try to stream the videos from the Nuxt application, I get a CORS error. I am using Videojs for playback in the frontend.

Videos are served directly from the public disk, and the urls are generated via:

```
Storage::disk('videos')->url('video_file.m3u8')
```

Of course I can access the videos directly when I paste the path in the browser, but streaming via the player returns a CORS error.

The exact error message I get from the browser is:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://api.test/media/videos/1/1586730833_samplevideo_1280x720_5mb.m3u8' from origin 'http://api.test:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Comment: What are the exact error messages that the browser is logging in the devtools console? You can use https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61183230/edit to edit/update the question and paste those messages in.

Comment: I've edited the question with the exact error message from the devtools.

Comment: What’s the HTTP status code of the response? You can use the Network pane in browser devtools to check. Is it a 4xx or 5xx error rather than a 200 OK success response?

Comment: The response code just says `(failed)` in the console. No specific code returned.

Comment: Have you tried it in different browsers? Firefox? Safari? (And do the same thing in those browsers: use the Network pane to inspect the request and response.)

Comment: Yes, I tried and Safari is same. But video loads fine when I play it from the same domain as the API.